# Using different JavaScript files based on map's zoom level in leaflet.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, leaflet

So I am trying to create a map-based visualization using leaflet.js. What I am trying to do is to use different GeoJSON files for different zoom levels of the map. For example when it is zoomed out, I would just like to display the state borders and when zoomed in, display county borders as well. I have the GeoJSON as a JavaScript variable in a `.js` file which I load in the body. It works fine when I want to load only one `.js` file, but when I dynamically want to change the `.js` file based on the zoom level, I am unable to figure out how to dynamically make the other `.js` file with the district GeoJSON data available.

The leaflet example I am referring to is [this](http://leafletjs.com/examples/choropleth.html) one. I looked into many SO questions dealing with dynamic `.js` file loading, but to no avail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used the `map.on()` property to achieve this. The code is as follows:

```
map.on('zoomend', function(e) {
  if (map.getZoom() > 5) {
    $.getScript('js/reassign_districts.js', function(data, textStatus, jqxhr) {
      console.log(textStatus); // Success
      console.log("Districts loaded.");
      if (jqxhr.status == 200) {
        map.removeLayer(geojson);
        loadGeoJson();
      }
    });
  } else if (map.getZoom() <= 5) {
    $.getScript('js/reassign_states.js', function(data, textStatus, jqxhr) {
      console.log(textStatus); // Success
      console.log("States loaded.");
      if (jqxhr.status == 200) {
        map.removeLayer(geojson);
        loadGeoJson();
      }
    });
  }
});
```

Some of the variables and functions, though not defined here, make sense as far as their names are concerned.